# Using standard \mathbb fonts in RevTex within Overleaf

Tags: fonts, overleaf, revtex

I am using the RevTex template of APS (American Physical Society) and the `\mathbb` fonts produce, for example these characters (for example for `\mathbb{E}`):

[image]

instead of the standard font

[image]

Note I do not want to use the fonts of the `\bbm` package. I just want the stadnard math fonts that come with any Latex distribution within the RevTex environment.

Comment: only use revtex if you are submitting to the APS, and if you are submitting to the APS don't change the font, it's their journal and they get to choose the design, not the author of each article.

Comment: I can use any fonts I like to actually, I have done this with `\bbm`. However, I do not like writing expectation values with the weird `\mathbb` of RevTex so this is why I ask.

Comment: Above is just standard advice for any journal class, the form you show is from amsfonts package, so presumably loading that will do what you want (if you tried that and it didn't work, show a small complete test file so people can debug)